# how to reduce the map content in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a map with 20 items. I want to use only 5 contents for display.

I used .slice but its not working.

```
{this.state.requisitions.slice(0, 5).map((req, key) => (
              <Col xs={2}>
                <SupplierView
                  org={req.org}
                  key={req.tableKey}
                />
              </Col>
            ))}
```

Constructor:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { req: [],};
  }
```

Comment: do you have a typo in your code? is the expected state property `req` or `requisitions`? Also please provide more details as to what exactly isn't working.

Comment: yeahh.. got it.. its working.. Thanks!!